# How to make a repeat pattern in for loop Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to make a repeat pattern to color background. But after `i` is over `colors.length` it starts not to change background color because for example `colors[3]` does not exists. But I'd like to make `colors[i]` return back 0 again until first for loop completed.

```
const arr = document.getElementById('collection');
const colors = ['#FFC6C6', '#A4BDFF', '#F9F9F9'];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.children.length; i++) {
    arr.children[i].style.background = colors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

```
const arr = document.getElementById('collection');
const colors = ['#FFC6C6', '#A4BDFF', '#F9F9F9'];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.children.length; i++) {
    arr.children[i].style.background = colors[i % colors.length];
}
```